# Initialize the final instance variable of inner class

Tags: java

Hello I want to initialize the final variable of inner class in it constructor but compiler forcing me to initialize it at the time of declaration Why Any idea ?

How can I handle this situation ?

```
public MainActivity extends Activity {
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
            private final BluetoothServerSocket mBluetoothServerSocket;
            public AcceptThread() {
                try {
                    mBluetoothServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("BT_SERVER", UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666"));
                } catch (IOException e) { }
            }

            // Here methods
    }
}
```

See here who answered to my question that seems weird here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The third doesn't work because you're trying to do more than one assignment to a `final` attribute (assignment to `null` is still an assignment). Try the approach that A Boschman suggested and pass the `BluetoothServerSocket` in as a parameter to the `AcceptThread` constructor.

Comment: Yes I know I shared all possibility of them but nothing worked for me that is weird

Comment: Did you try passing the `BluetoothServerSocket` into the constructor as a parameter?

Comment: No I don't want to use here Argument Constructor

Comment: In that case ghik's latest suggestion about using a local variable in the `try` and then assigning its value to the `final` afterwards is probably your best bet.

Comment: All right ! but Why first approach did not work for me, where I initialized the final variable in catch also, see the screenshot ?

Comment: I would assume it's because the compiler can't be 100% certain that your variable didn't get an assignment inside the `try` block, so it has to assume that it's possible to hit the `catch` after an assignment has taken place.

Comment: @JonK Yes I got, Nice +1

Comment: @Mick I edited my answer once again to explain that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not that you are trying to initialize the field in constructor, but the fact that you don't initialize it in the `catch` block. The compiler must be sure that the field will *always* get initialized before exiting constructor.

Unfortunately, simply assigning a fallback value in the `catch` block will not work, because when compiler sees code like this:

```
try {
    ...
    someFinalField = ...
    ...
} catch {
    ...
    someFinalField = ...
    ...
}
```

... then it sees a possibility for the field to be initialized *twice* (once in the `try` block and second time in the `catch` block), which is illegal for `final` fields. In your simple case we clearly see that this is impossible, because the exception will always be thrown *before* the field is initialized in the `try` block, but unfortunately the compiler isn't smart enough to understand that.

You can satisfy the compiler by throwing an exception from the `catch` block, which would probably be a preferred option in your case:

```
catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

or, using very popular [guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

```
catch (IOException e) {
    throw Throwables.propagate(e);
}
```

If you really want to swallow the exception, then - to ensure that the field always gets initialized exactly once, you have to move the initialization outside of `try-catch` block:

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mBluetoothServerSocket;
    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket localBluetoothServerSocket;
        try {
            localBluetoothServerSocket = ...
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            localBluetoothServerSocket = ...
        }
        mBluetoothServerSocket = localBluetoothServerSocket;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also do something like `throw new InstantiationException("Error initialising socket");` if it's not something you can/should recover from.

Comment: Further more think of what happens when the try fails, tehnn you have an Object (AcceptThread) which is not valid but exists. Constructors should not be able to fail! and should not throw Exceptions!

Comment: No, can you see my question again that seems very weird now. I can not use which you are saying because this is not available for Android

Comment: @Mick You mean guava? You can still simply throw a `RuntimeException`, you don't need a library for that. Also, see my later suggestion about using a local variable in constructor.

Comment: Why first approach did not work for me, where I initialized the final variable in catch also, see the screenshot

Comment: @Mick Because for the compiler, it looks like the field could get initialized in the `try` block, then an exception could be thrown and the field would be assigned second time in the `catch` block, which is illegal for final fields. We know that this is impossible in your case, but the compiler isn't that smart. That's why I suggested using a local variable, so please read my entire answer.

Comment: +1 for the second suggestion to use a local variable in the try/catch block. Of course, you may not use a function call in the catch part (or wrap it in another try/catch).

Comment: Oh Nice "compiler isn't that smart" but we are :) +1

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's inside a try-block, and therefore the final variable isn't instantiated in all cases.

Revised answer: Ask for the object as a parameter. Doing work in the constructor is generally not a good idea anyway.

Comment: No, Android docs says same which I am doing http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices

Comment: +1 - passing the socket in as a parameter to the constructor is the best way to be approaching this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't not guarantee that it initializes the `final` field. If an exception occurs, you catch it and ignore it, and then you haven't assigned any value to your final field yet.

Change your code to:

```
public AcceptThread() throws IOException {
    mBluetoothServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("BT_SERVER", UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666"));
}
```

Comment: Changed the answer - making sure that you either assign `mBluetoothServerSocket` or throw the exception is enough. You can catch the exception and change it to another exception as well.

Comment: +1 Nice Thanks ! but we can have public constructor in a private inner class.